# .NET XML Output Loses Line Breaks

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to add a comment to an existing XML document.  The document, when opened in an XML reader (I use notepad++), is formatted perfectly.  However, when I run it through my code that simply adds a comment to the top the XML comes out as one long line.  In other words, all the line breaks have been removed.  How to I maintain my line breaks?

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(doc.Uri);

//This is where I add comments to a string

xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(enrichedDoc.CreateComment(comments));

return xmlDoc;
```

Comment: I think you mean line breaks, not page breaks.

Comment: Dang it!  You are right, line breaks is what I meant to say.  editing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: As an aside, what if you want to preserve whitespace in some elements but not others? Surely there should be an attribute for that?

Comment: @Tom W: can you provide a case in which you'd require it? I'm having a hard time imagining what you're aiming for.

Comment: Any application where storage of verbatim text should occur along with normal behaviour. I'd turn your question around and ask: under what circumstances should the need to store verbatim text in a particular element change the behaviour of the whole document?

Comment: @Tom W: I'd think that if you want to preserve formatting in some elements but not others you'd use CDATA nodes in the elements for which you want to preserve formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [PreserveWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace.aspx) property:

```
xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
```